# Chimney work - blocking a fireplace temporarily

Tags: chimney

We live in a house which is a good 100 or so years old and the chimney has been causing us problems with leaking into our loft room for some time now.

A local builder has taken on the job of re-rendering the outside of the chimney with K-Rend. On the first day on the job when removing the old render we experienced a bit of soot falling down so we put some good quality floor protection fabric over it secured with masking tape.

I’ve come home today to a bit of a disaster in that the ‘solution’ to block the chimney didn’t really last, and after a ‘henry the hoover’s worth of soot and some brickwork fell down the chimney the solution seems to have been blown out and I’ve spent the last 3 hours cleaning my living room.

What is the best solution here to stop dust / soot entering the house whilst allowing the work on the chimney to proceed?